# URL prefix to include one PHP page

Tags: php

is it possible to set one URL prefix to include one PHP page every time? Only Wordpress header and this PHP page.
I need to include some custom application but HAVE TO include wordpress powered web-design.

For example - http://my.web.com/customapp/ is a prefix and

```
http://my.web.com/customapp/
http://my.web.com/customapp/some/function1
http://my.web.com/customapp/some/function2/x/y
```

points to one PHP page included in Wordpress theme-page.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you look into creating a Template for this site? Here you can find a ressource on the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [**`get_template_part()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part).

For example, in your `index.php` template file:

```
/**
 * Index template file
 */

/**
 * Include header
 */
get_header();

/**
 * Include arbitrary file
 */
get_template_part( 'foobar' );
```

This will include a template-part file, `foobar.php`, located in the Theme's root directory.

Comment: Where is this file located, please? I don't know Wordpress very well.
Is it possible to use this and show own title of page in title bar?

Comment: Where is what file located? Please make your question more descriptive, if you want more precise answers.

Comment: I'm sorry. 1) The file you mentioned - index.php - is located in \wp-content\themes\my-theme\index.php, right?
2) Is it possible to set own title of the page (in title bar)?

Comment: First question: yes. Theme template files go in `wp-content/themes/{theme-name}`. Your second question is entirely unrelated.

Comment: I'm playing with wordpress and it looks like index.php is included only sometimes. I need to include some application under wordpress so I need load application's loader file, change page title and not to trigger 404 page not found error.

Comment: All in one SEO pack was rewriting my title tag. Now I'm loading my application from 404.php page. Cleanest solution.